# Changing UITableView Cell's Height by using storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm using Swift5 and Xcode 11.4.1 on macOS Catalina.

**main.storyboard**
[image: Main storyboard image]

As you can see here, I selected tableview cell, went to the size inspector and changed the height as 100 and hit enter.
It is successfully changed as 100 height on storyboard but when I run this thing,

**Simulator screenshot**
[image: Simulator screenshot]

It looks like this, the image link above.
The height is set as 44 not 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to the class that conform's to your `UITableView`'s `delegate` to change the tableView's height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```